# Overview of classes that are available in a package or nodes

Tags: ros, nodes

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

We all know the following line:

> ros::Nodehandle n;

what i understand is that "i am instantiating n from a class called NodeHandle that is in a package called ros"

My question is: how do i know / find the classes that are defined in a node or package, without opening every possible file that is available on the ros directory

thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9564/overview-of-classes-that-are-available-in-a-package-or-nodes/) by [whiterose](https://answers.ros.org/users/349/whiterose/) on ROS Answers with karma: 148 on 2011-03-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Checkout the Code API documentation in the roscpp package:
http://www.ros.org/doc/api/roscpp/html/

Also the overview gives nice implementation examples:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2